# Need to add a Show more/less javascript in Magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, toggle, e-commerce

Need to add show more/less on category description section in Magento.
but whenever i add any link in the category description section then it is getting copied in the title too, which is disturbing the layout of the page as well.
So how i can add a script for toggling the text in the description section of the product_category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a div with a unique id and fetch the description in that div in your phtml file i.e.(example for production)

```
<a id="link-refer">HIDE/SHOW</a>
<div id="catalog-description">
<?php echo $product->getDescription(); ?>
</div>
```

If the phtml file is rendered in category view.
Add your javascript code in the head.phtml

```
jQuery("#link-refer").click(function{
jQuery("#catalog-description").toggle();
});
```

This just an idea you could customize as per your reuirenment

Comment: i just need to toggle the text in category description..
which i am not able to as whenever i create a <div> in description using html editor but that is getting copied in title section too automatically and disrupting me to do any change ...

Comment: Its most probably because your theme has some missing "DIV" or some extra  "DIV" added.Please check the template for any extra div as well as check on the page source.This will help you some what to fix the problem.